# How to make anchor tags added in JEditorPane clikcable? (Java)

Tags: java, html, swing, url, jeditorpane

I have the below code to add html into a JEditorPane

```
        JEditorPane  content = new JEditorPane ();

        content.setEditable(false);
        content.setContentType( "text/html" );

        content.setText(resultText);

        JScrollPane bottomScrollPane = new JScrollPane(content);
        bottomScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        bottomScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Swing Rendered"));
```

After this step, i have added the JEditorPane instance "content" into a JPanel instance and
can able to see the result perfectly. But when i try to click the links shown, its not working.

How do i make these links clickable and it should redirect user to specific url in the browser?

regards,
Balan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add HyperlinkListener to the JEditorPane:

```
pane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
{
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent r){
        try{
            if(r.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)
            pane.setPage(r.getURL());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
 });
```

Or you can do anything else in the listener... for example, opening a link in the default browser:

You need to add HyperlinkListener to the JEditorPane:

```
pane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener()
{
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent r){
        try{
            if(r.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED)
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(r.getURL().toURI()));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: I tried this code, i want to make the link open in a browser window.. not inline in pane..